# Can I use LockService to lock a script AND a spreadsheet - Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, lock-service

I am using a Google Apps Script to manage registration data, for a small festival, from a Form.

Two simultaneous submissions both populate the Form results spreadsheet but then the script runs the wrong data from the form on the second trigger. Simultaneous submissions are unlikely, but I'm curious if there is a way to lock the spreadsheet AND the script at the same time to prevent the issue described below.

The script pulls the newest data from the Form results sheet.

I lock the script while it's running, but when I tested simultaneous Form submissions, the Form still populates the Form results sheet (with the second submission) while the first script is running. The result is; participant 1 submits a form, it triggers the script (and locks it). Participant 2 submits a form before the script pulls participant 1 data. The script runs on participant 2 data, the script lock is released, then the script runs on the waiting trigger and runs participant 2 data again.

If I were to only lock the spreadsheet, the second trigger would just run the script a second time, before the second participant's data was populated in the spreadsheet (doubling participant 1's data, instead of participant 2 when the script is locked).

The Form is going live today, it's a tiny festival (roughly 50 participants) so the chances of simultaneous submissions is extremely small, so I won't actually try to implement a solution this time around. I am curious if it's possible to lock the Form results spreadsheet, while the script is also locked, from a single trigger. I would implement it next time if that were the case.

```
function getData(event) {
  const lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
  lock.tryLock(120000);

  const festivalSsId = 'spreadsheet ID removed for public post';
  const festivalSs = SpreadsheetApp.openById(festivalSsId);
  const formDataSheet = festivalSs.getSheetByName('Form Data');
  const participantsSheet = festival.getSheetByName('Participants');
  const revenueCostsSheet = festival.getSheetByName('Revenue and costs');
  const gearRequestsSheet = festival.getSheetByName('Gear Requests');

  formDataSheet.sort(1,false); //sorts form results sheet with newest submission first

  //
  //removed most of the functional portion of script for this post
  //

  var mwcWaiverArray = createMwcWaiver(firstName,lastName,emergencyContact,emergencyContactPhoneNum,clinicYesNo,participantCharges);

  Drive.Files.remove(mwcWaiverArray[1]);
  Utilities.sleep(200);

sendEmailFunc(participantName, participantEmail, mwcWaiverArray, clinicYesNo,participantCharges);
Utilities.sleep(200);

Drive.Files.remove(mwcWaiverArray[2]);

 lock.releaseLock();
```